# Apache Camel - Special characters in message body

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using Camel version 3.1 and trying to send message from one ActiveMQ server to another using [AMQP Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/amqp-component.html) with Spring boot. After sending the message, at the destination ActiveMQ Console the message details is having the below content.

```
Sp�ASr�)�x-opt-jms-destQ�x-opt-jms-msg-typeQSs�^
�/ID:53e1ce3a-4drf-4f8a-9ff9-845fe0d0006e:3:1:1-1@�queue://testcamelwithamqp@@@@@@�qd�Sw�1:"test message"
```

My actual message is `1:"test message"`, but somehow the JMS headers are put in message body as special characters. Any help to resolve?

Below is spring boot code sample

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class CamelMQApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelMQApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent;
import org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AmqpConfigInternal {

    @Value("${INTERNAL_SERVICE_USERNAME}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${INTERNAL_SERVICE_PASSWORD}")
    private String pass;
    @Value("${INTERNAL_REMOTE_URI}")
    private String remoteUri;

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelInternal;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getRemoteUri() {
        return remoteUri;
    }

    public void setRemoteUri(String remoteUri) {
        this.remoteUri = remoteUri;
    }

    private JmsConnectionFactory internalConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory();
        jmsConnectionFactory.setRemoteURI(remoteUri);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setUsername(userName);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setPassword(pass);
        return jmsConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AMQPComponent internalAmqpConnection() throws Exception {
        AMQPComponent amqp = new AMQPComponent();
        amqp.setConnectionFactory(internalConnectionFactory());
        camelInternal.addComponent("amqpInternal", amqp);
        return amqp;
    }

}
```

```
import org.apache.camel.ExchangePattern;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SampleAutowiredAmqpRouteTest extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("{{route1.from}}")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
        .removeHeaders("*")
        .log("From ActiveMQ: ${body}")
        .to("{{route1.to}}")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
        .removeHeaders("*");

    }

}
```

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent;
import org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AmqpConfigRouteTest {

    @Value("${ACTIVEMQ_SERVICE_USERNAME}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${ACTIVEMQ_SERVICE_PASSWORD}")
    private String pass;
    @Value("${ACTIVEMQ_REMOTE_URI}")
    private String remoteUri;

    @Autowired private CamelContext camelRouteTest;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getRemoteUri() {
        return remoteUri;
    }

    public void setRemoteUri(String remoteUri) {
        this.remoteUri = remoteUri;
    }

    private JmsConnectionFactory amqp1ConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory();
        jmsConnectionFactory.setRemoteURI(remoteUri);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setUsername(userName);
        jmsConnectionFactory.setPassword(pass);
        return jmsConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AMQPComponent amqp1Connection() throws Exception {
        AMQPComponent amqp = new AMQPComponent();
        amqp.setConnectionFactory(amqp1ConnectionFactory());
        camelRouteTest.addComponent("amqpRouteTest", amqp);
        return amqp;
    }
}
```

```
application.properties

server.port=8071
camel.springboot.name = CamelTest
camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true

INTERNAL_REMOTE_URI=amqp://actimqserver1:12345
INTERNAL_SERVICE_USERNAME=admin
INTERNAL_SERVICE_PASSWORD=admin

ACTIVEMQ_REMOTE_URI=amqp://actimqserver2:12345
ACTIVEMQ_SERVICE_USERNAME=admin
ACTIVEMQ_SERVICE_PASSWORD=admin

route1.from = amqpInternal:test4camelamqpSrcQ
route1.to = amqpRouteTest:test4camelamqpTgtQ
```

Comment: What if you actually consume the message rather than look at the content in the console? Perhaps the data is corrupted or perhaps the console just has a bug in the display logic.

Comment: Can you give us more information like the code that are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram, I tried getting the message using `@JmsListener` and I am seeing the same spl charaters in the jms message output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: We need to add the `transport.transformer=jms` in the ActiveMQ config file as shown below and restart the Active MQ

```xml
<transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://localhost:5672?transport.transformer=jms"/>
```

This will actually let ActiveMQ to correctly map the incoming JMS Message headers. The default value of `transport.transformer=native` wraps the AMQP message into a JMS `BytesMessage`, due to this its neither not properly displayed in the console or when the message is actually consumed by a client.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **ActiveMQ with the AMQP protocol**. Have you also [configured the broker](https://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html) for this protocol?

For example a transport connector:

```
<transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672"/>
```

To be honest **I don't know what happens when you use a plain ActiveMQ broker (default protocol is OpenWire) and send AMQP messages to it**.

In your case, Camel seems to be able to produce and consume messages correctly to/from a queue. This is not very surprising since **both producer and consumer are configured for AMQP**. The broker just stores the message.

On the other hand, you write that Springs JmsListener messes up the message on consumption. Probably because it **does not expect an AMQP message** and you try to receive a JMS message (TextMessage, ByteMessage etc).

You could try to simply receive a `Message<?>` which is a **Spring abstraction over multiple transports**.

That the message is messed up in the ActiveMQ Console is no big surprise. I guess that an AMQP message has a specific format and the console cannot display it correctly because it differs from a JMS message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the transformer transport option as "jms" on the transportConnector in activemq.xml and restart your ActiveMQ Server.

For example:

```
transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5673?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.transformer=jms"
```

refer:
https://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html